# How to prove the formula has no finite model, thus it has no finit domain

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I am not sure how to even start solving this problem. I tried to solve it using the semantic tree, but with no success. 
It’s an exercise from the book **Mathematical Logic for Computer Science by Mordechai Ben-Ari**, page 154, exercise 7.10.

Prove that the following formula has no finite models:
∀x∃yp(x,y)∧∀x¬p(x,x)∧∀x∀y∀z(p(x,y)∧p(y,z)→p(x,z)).

Comment: Start with $x_0$, let $x_1$ be such that $p(x_0,x_1)$, and so on. Argue that the $x_n$ are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $p$ is transitive and irreflexive. Hence, it is also asymmetric, and thus a strict partial order. This means that all objects can be ordered accordingly. Moreover, given any finite number of objects, that means that there is a 'smallest' element, i.e. an element $x$ such that for no $y$: $p(x,y)$.  However, that contradicts the $\forall x \exists y p(x,y)$. So, the domain cannot be finite.