# difference between languages whit n-adic and monadic predicates

Tags: first-order-logic

For FOL language, we can distinguish between languages with only monadic predicates and languages with relational/n-adic predicates.
Reading a paper, I stumbledupon this claim:

> When we move to a quantificational language with relational predicates
> (but not identity) our situation is complicated by the fact that some
> formulae have no finite models.

Why does languages without n-adic relations do not encounter this problem, and what does precisely a "finite model" mean in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a model (of some FO formula $\varphi$ over some signature $\tau$) is a $\tau$-*structure* $\mathcal A$ such that $\varphi$ holds in $\mathcal A$.
Such a $\tau$-structure $\mathcal A$ consists of some set $A$ (called the universe of $\mathcal A$) and an interpretation of the relation symbols (and, if you allow them, function symbols) in your signature $\tau$, i.e. a specification of which elements or tuples in $A$ are in the predicates of $\tau$.
A structure is finite if its universe is.

Let us now get to your first question, which can be reformulated as "why do formulae over signatures only consisting of monadic predicates have finite models?".
I will not give an actual proof but rather an outline of one, I am sure that you can easily find a complete proof online.

So consider some signature $\tau = \{P_1, ..., P_n\}$ only consisting of monadic predicates and some satisfiable formula $\varphi$ over $\tau$.
As $\varphi$ is satisfiable, that means that there exists some model $\mathcal A$ of $\varphi$ over some universe $A$ which might be infinite.
A key observation here is that $\varphi$ has no way to distinguish elements of $A$ which have exactly the same predicates.
This yields an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the universe $A$ with two elements $a, b \in A$ having $a \sim b$ saying that $a \in P_k$ if and only $b \in P_k$ in $\mathcal A$ for all $k$.
This equivalence relation finitely many equivalence classes, in fact the number of them is $2^n$ (as any element of $A$ can either has some predicate $P_k$ or not, and we have $n$ such predicates).
Now consider the $\tau$-structure $\mathcal{A}'$ over the universe made up of these $2^n$ equivalence classes, with the interpretation of the predicates being that some equivalence class is in $P_k$ if it's members were in $P_k$ in $\mathcal A$.
It can be shown that $\mathcal{A}' \models \varphi$ if and only if $\mathcal A \models \varphi$, and hence $\varphi$ has a finite model.

This is no longer the case if we allow binary predicates into our signature (or even larger ones), see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459003/how-to-prove-the-formula-has-no-finite-model-thus-it-has-no-finit-domain).